# RDF express the degree of a predicate

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

Let's say I have this triple:

```
m:song1 m:hasFeature m:harmony
```

that means a song with uri `m:song1` has harmony, okay cool so far, but sometimes I want to say that it has harmony just 40% .

A better example may be this:

```
m:user1 m:fromPeriod m:adult
m:user2 m:fromPeriod m:childhood
```

We can't say that before 25 years old you are childhood and after you are adult, it is fuzzy, not hard cut. I want to say that you are 50% adult and 50% childhood

Is there any way to do that in RDF and how if yes (I hope) in Protege

What i think of is this:

```
m:user1 m:fromPeriod m:adult
m:fromPeriod :hasFuzzy 0.5
```

is that possible? (specially in Protege because I can't write in hand in the whole ontology)

Comment: You can use the N-ary relation pattern to do that: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)), which is a common practise on the Semantic Web and elsewhere. Using [n-ary relations](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) as recommended in the comments is one way, and probably the right way.

Another technique is to assign a URI, or bnode, to your statement (triple) so that you can make statements about it. For example,

Given triple:

```
:song_1 :hasFeature :harmony.
```

you can create:

```
:statement_1 a rdf:Statement.
:statement_1 rdf:subject :song_1.
:statement_1 rdf:predicate :hasFeature.
:statement_1 rdf:object :harmony.
```

then you can say things like:

```
:statement_1 :hasSomeValue "40%".
```

Answer (score 0):

I may also check some resource on fuzzy logic with Protégé like [this one](http://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2009/abstracts/S10P2Ghorbel.pdf).

Comment: Can you add a summary of the information to your actual answer instead of just posting a link to it? That way the information is preserved and the answer remains useful even if the link goes dead. You can [edit] your answer to update it.